# Replace bracketed string with string wrapped in HTML H1 tags

Tags: php, regex

I think this is probably a fairly common but I haven't found a match in any of the previously answered SO questions.

If I have a string like this:

> [Our Story] The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. [Our
>   analysis] whatever...

and want to replace the bracketed string with `<h1>str</h1>` then how could I do this?  This is similar to implementing the {} code option in this SO window.

Comment: Please don't tag your question title. Can you tell us what regex you've tried, if any?

Comment: I haven't tried any regular expressions myself because I wouldn't know how to replace only the []'s in the string while retaining its inner content.  I'm not very good with regular expressions though, and I'm aware that there probably is some way to accomplish this using them.  Appologies if I put a tag in the title, I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use what is called a backreference.  in this instance, \1 represents the bracketed portion of the regex pattern.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\[(.*)\]/', '<h1>\1</h1>', $string)
```

Comment: Surely only a single `\\` is needed with the `\\1` seeing as it's inside a literal (single quoted) string anyway?

Comment: The `[` and `]` on the other hand probably need quoting... I'm a bit suprised to see the `/` there, too, but PHP was never very consistent...

Comment: I think any character may be used for this purpose, `#`, `~`, and `/` are the most commonly used, and I don't know if this has anything to do with php...

Comment: Well, it didn't work the first time around but it works like a charm now that its been edited :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Raw regexp substitution in perl-style: `s/\[(.*?)\]/<h1>\1<\/h1>/g`